# How to set handler for WebRequest.GetResponseAsync in IronRuby?

Tags: asynchronous, webrequest, ironruby

I'm trying:

```
request = WebRequest.Create( uri )
responseTask = request.GetResponseAsync
action = Action.new { process_request( sender, e ) }
task = Task.new( action )
responseTask.Wait( TimeSpan.new( -1 ) )
responseTask.ContinueWith( task )
```

But have following error:

```
can't convert System::Threading::Tasks::Task into System::Action[System::Threading::Tasks::Task] (TypeError)
```

**UPD**

On

```
responseTask = request.GetResponseAsync  
action = Action[Task].new { process_request( sender, e ) }  
responseTask.Wait( TimeSpan.new( -1 ) )  
responseTask.ContinueWith( action )
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Found multiple methods for 'ContinueWith': ContinueWith(System::Action[System::Threading::Tasks::Task]), ContinueWith(System::Action[System::Threading::Tasks::Task[System::Net::WebResponse]]) (System::Reflection::AmbiguousMatchException)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ContinueWith takes an

```
Action<Task>
```

and has other overloads, but not for a Task.

eg:

```
action = Action.new {Console.WriteLine("action")}
task = Task.new( action )
action2 = Action[Task].new{Console.WriteLine("action2")}
task.ContinueWith(action2)
task.Start()
#prints "action" then "action2".
```

---

<s>IronRuby may let you skip generic type specialisations</s> That was the non-generic Task, here is the fully typed version for your problem:

```
 action = Action[Task[WebResponse]].new { process_request( sender, e ) }
```

Comment: Can you show me working example? http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.threading.tasks.task(v=vs.110).aspx `Task` requieres `Action` for argument on initialization. `responseTask.ContinueWith( action )` get the same error.

Comment: I'm try it but have an error, look at **UPD** section.